# Was the tearing down of the Wall of Separation between Jew and Gentile, mentioned in Ephesians 2:14, to be permanent or temporary?

Tags: gospels, ephesians, oneness

Paul wrote to the Ephesian congregation a message of hope concerning the long-held attitude of Separation between the Jewish race and the Gentiles (ethnics) concerning religious practices...and Redemption itself:

> *Now in Christ Jesus you who once were far away have been brought near through the blood of Christ For He Himself is our peace, Who has made the two one and has destroyed the barrier, the dividing wall of hostility, by abolishing in His flesh the Law with its commandments and regulations.*

> *His purpose was to create in Himself one new man out of the two, thus making peace, and in this one Body to reconcile both of them to God through the cross, by which He put to death their hostility.* (Ephesians 2:13-16)

Is there any **scriptural evidence** that states that this Separation is no longer in effect? Has the Wall been re-erected by God? Is the Church of Christ to look upon Jew and Gentile as two distinct groups again?

We have been told by Tim LaHaye in his book, *No Fear of the Storm*, that a J.N. Darby was informed by an Irishman, Mr. Tweedy, that one can only understand the Bible when a separation between Jew and Gentile are kept distinct as a matter of biblical history, past and future.  This became the foundation of the Dispensational movement in modern times, which teaches a Separation of destinies between Jew and Gentile (and some even advocate two different "salvations.")

But is there *scripture* in the New Testament Covenant Era that speaks of a re-erection of the Wall that Paul said was torn down? Was the **Christ-led demolition** to be permanent? (Perhaps symbolized by the utter Destruction of the Temple a few year later! No Temple, No separate courts, No wall!) Or was this to be a temporary situation? {Put another way, is the Gospel of Christ an eternal Gospel or temporary one?}

{As a matter of history: there was a physical barrier wall in the Temple separating the Court of the Gentiles from the Court of Israel! And there was a sign posted which stated that any Gentile crossing through would be punished by death. *The hostility Paul referred to(?).* This was the wall that the Pharisees accused Paul of violating when he was in the Temple with Greek Christians. (Acts 21:27-36)}

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known that the Jews, and especially the Pharisees, were both racist and spiritually (and theologically) proud and elitist.  One of the functions of Jesus' teaching was to dismantle that elitism in His teaching in Luke 17:20, 21 and Mark 13:38. (See appendix below).  Jesus summed this up when He said (quoting Isa 56:7):

> Mark 11:17 - Then Jesus began to teach them, and He declared, “Is it
> not written: ‘My house will be called a house of prayer for all the
> nations’? But you have made it ‘a den of robbers.’ ”

Thus, the temple should have been open to all, including gentiles.

Paul said the same thing:

- Gal 3:26-29 - You are all sons of God through faith in Christ Jesus. For all of you who were baptized into Christ have clothed yourselves with Christ. There is **neither Jew nor Greek**, slave nor free, male nor female, for you are all one in Christ Jesus. And if **you belong to Christ, then you are Abraham’s seed** and heirs according to the promise.
- Rom 9:8 - So it is not the children of the flesh who are God’s children, but it is the children of the promise who are regarded as offspring.

Therefore, the "dividing wall" was a cultural one and not a real theological barrier that had been false erected by the elitism of the Jews.  Both Jesus and Paul emphasized this.

**APPENDIX - Jews vs Gentiles**

The covenant promises were always open to all people and was never exclusive.  For example:

- Abraham’s own household must have consisted of perhaps 2000 people just to be able to raise an army of 318 men to liberate Lot, Gen 14:14.  Indeed, Abraham’s chief servant (from Damascus) was clearly a believer and very devout as shown in Gen 24.
- The unfortunate story in Gen 38 about Judah and Tamar shows that a foreigner became the mother of the tribe of Judah.
- When Jacob entered Egypt, his family numbered 75 people (Acts 7:14, Ex 1:5).  Some of these were not direct descendants of Abraham such as the wives of the 12 patriarchs, notably Joseph’s own wife.  215 years and four generations later at the exodus, Israel’s army had over 600,000 men, excluding women and children, (Ex 12:37, Num 1:46, etc) suggesting a total population of several million people, requiring many additions.  This included a significant mixed multitude (Ex 12:38) showing that Israel obviously consisted of many non-biological Jews had joined.  (Note that it is biologically impossible for Israelite numbers to have grown from 75 to several million biologically without many outside additions.)
- Moses married a Midianite (Ex 2:16-21) also known as a Cushite.  Miriam and Aaron were severely reprimanded and punished for displaying racism (Num 12:1, 2)
- Caleb, who represented and led the tribe of Judah was a Kennizite (Num 32:12).
- Rahab was a Canaanite (Josh 2:1, 2, Matt 1:5)
- Ruth was Moabite (Ruth 1:4 16, 17, Matt 1:5) – these last two make King David descended from foreigners (Ruth 4:13-16).
- Uriah was a Hittite (2 Sam 11:3)
- King David’s elite personal (and very loyal) regiment consisted of Gittites, that is, Philistines (2 Sam 15:18-22, 1 Chron 18:17)
- Isa 56:6, 7 - And the foreigners who join themselves to the LORD to minister to Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My covenant—I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful in My house of prayer.  Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for My house will be called a house of prayer for all the nations.”  See also V3.
- The Rechabites were Kenites (Jer 35:1-19)
- Many other foreigners lived in Israel (1 Chron 22:2, 17, 2 Chron 30:25)
- In Esther’s time “many of the people of the land became Jews” (Esther 8:17, 9:27)
- Even in NT times, many Jewish synagogues were attended by godly gentiles converted to Judaism (Acts 13:16, 26, 16:14, 17:17)
- Many Jewish proselytes came to worship in Jerusalem (John 20:20, Acts 2:9-11)
- Jesus quotes Isa 56:7, “My house shall be a house of prayer for all nations”, Mark 11:17.

Comment: @Dottard- Interesting response! Would you go so far as to say that, while the Jewish attitude towards Gentiles (apart from the _god-fearers_) was cultural or nationalistic, still, it took a _spiritually redemptive_ and extraordinary blood Sacrifice on the part of God in order to be able to facilitate a reunion of men's spirits in brotherhood? A theological coup that overcomes all types of racism? A spiritual conquest that breaks through the hardest of hearts?! Peace!....And will any WALL REPAIR CONSTRUCTION prophetic group be able to negate this demolition by Jesus?

Comment: @raygrant - I fully agree.  The sinful nature of humanity destroyed both the vertical (with God) and horizontal relationship of humanity.  Only God can reconcile us in both cases.